# Prevent/block/hide images from certain site source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey I have a trolling problem at my forum.

Long story short:

There is a troll who comes and posts images from a number of gore sites. In fact this person hotlinks them directly from the source. For obvious reasons, I want to put this to an end.

I was thinking of implementing a code that does the following:

> 1. Checks the source of an image before allowing it to load.
> 2. If the src of the image is a url that contains the word 'gore', the image is NOT displayed.

While I realize this isn't a permanent solution, I think this is a step in the right direction. Thoughts? Any idea how I can get started?

JQuery is really a foreign "language" to me but it seems like that's what I need.
In the code below `c_post` stands for the actual post, meaning this code targets only images posted inside posts. What I want the code to do is select for the word 'gore'.

`$('c_post img[src*="gore"]').attr({ hide(); })`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can accomplish this with a RegEx check

`if ( $('c_post img').attr('src').match(/gore/) ) { 
    $('c_post img').attr("src", "filteredimage")
}`

If the image's src attribute matches the RegExp, you'd be able rewrite the src url to a specific image of your choice.

or, if you just want to hide it you could instead do the following inside the if statement:

`$('c_post img').css("display", "none")`